# How to make tkinter window pop-up when a certain if statement is triggered?

Tags: python, tkinter, window-managers

Hey guys so I am trying to make a timer app for studying which pops-up when break time is triggered. I am using this code to bring the window up, but the issue I am facing is if I minimize the window this code does not work anymore and the app does not pop-up. I tried to find a way to just remove the minimize button option from the window but didn't come across anything.

```
def raise_above_all(window):
    window.attributes('-topmost', 1)
    window.attributes('-topmost', 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.deiconify()` to make it un-minimize, and use your code to make it go to front. Like this:

```
window.deiconify()
window.attributes('-topmost', 1)
window.attributes('-topmost', 0)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't go for disabling the window's minimize button. Just use `window.state('zoomed')` along with `window.attributes('-topmost', True)`. This way even if the window was minimized, still it will be raised to the topmost level.
Also, define the window's `maxsize` prior, so that the window does not become fullscreen due to `zoomed`.

Here is a simple yet complete demonstration:
(To raise the window "window2", you would need to Enter 1 in the entry box of "window1")

```
from tkinter import *


window1 = Tk()
window1.geometry('1200x600')
window1.minsize(1200, 600)

def raise_above_all(window):
    window.state('zoomed')  #Needed in case the window2 is minimized
    window.attributes('-topmost', True)

def create_new_window2(window):
    window.maxsize(300, 300)    #define the maxsize so that the window2 does not get fullscreen when 'zoomed'
    window.mainloop()

def submit():
    if x.get()==1:
        raise_above_all(window2)
    else:
        print("Enter 1")
        
x = IntVar()
Entry(window1, textvariable=x).pack()
Button(window1, text="Enter", command=submit).pack()

window2 = Tk()
create_new_window2(window2)

window1.mainloop()
```

---

Alternatively, you can just remove the entire window's title bar using `window.overrideredirect(True)`